# How to add multiple lines in text file

Tags: c, file, file-io, append

I am trying to write a program which can display the contents of the file then append the content dynamically by user to a text file in C.

Below is the code, but somehow it is working for single line input and not for multi-line input even in the loop.

```
fobj=fopen("test3.txt","a");
if (fobj==NULL)
 {
  printf("Error opening the file.  ");
  exit(0);

 }
int contd;
char buff1[120];
char *chptr;
do
{
printf("Enter line : \n");

gets(buff1);

fputs(buff1,fobj);

printf("Enter Continuation code : ");
scanf("%d",&contd);

}while(contd!=0);
```

Comment: add line break char for every tail of line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing the typical stdin issue.  You can use `fflush(stdin);` before gets, should work.

Answer (score 0):

From [gets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/):

```
The newline character, if found, is not copied into str.
```

So you will have to add the new line manually:

```
gets(buff1);
strcat(buff1, "\n");
```

Comment: surely i have added that but the problem is when the loop is iterated for the first time it takes the input for line but after the first iteration it just asks for continuation code not for the line input ... i am sorry but this is my first post so any errors are regretted ..

Comment: @user2349530 Isn't this intended? After fputs, you ask for the continuation code inside the loop. if you then enter something that is not 0, the loop will continue to ask you for a new line input

Comment: very true but the main aim is to take the input from the user.After the first iteration it is directly jumping to enter the continuation code it is not taking the input form the user .. in simple terms it is not letting the user to type the input..